# Is there a way that a web developer can code an app to prevent a user from downloading, saving, printing, or taking a screenshot of a PDF?

Tags: pdf, printing, download

I am wondering if there is a way to ensure that a PDF is "read-only" in the browser regardless of the permission settings tied to the PDF itself. Here is a possible scenario. Someone uploads a PDF to my site that is wide open in terms of permissions. As a developer, do I have a way to prevent users from downloading, printing, saving, or taking a screenshot of it? In other words, I want the user to be able to "read" the PDF in the browser, but not have the ability to download, print, or save, or screenshot it.

(I am using C#.Net in an MVC environment.)

Comment: there's no way you could make it 100% foolproof.  The person could take a picture of it with their phone.

Comment: No. The data needs to be moved to the client's computer in order for him to view it and at that point anything can be done with the data.

Comment: If there is, the Motion Picture industry would love to know!

Comment: Could watermarking your PDF accomplish your goals?

Comment: You could get the window size from the client, and then render the PDF to an image just of that size; you may allow zooming, but then you again render to the window size. This would prevent the PDF from leaving your server; screenshots are still possible, however.

Answer (score 7):

No there's no way to prevent copying the data from the PDF files. If it's on screen then the user can screenshot it and even if somehow you disable that they can run the browser inside a VM and use that to take a screenshot and if somehow you find a way to prevent that they can take a picture of their monitor.

There will always be a way to copy the data if it is presented to the user's browser.